# Use variable to call a previously defined object within a class in python pyqt6

Tags: python, self, pyqt6

I'm working with PyQt6. I've set up a grid layout of a bunch of different labels called b0, b1...b6...d1... I have a letter dictionary that is edited whenever I input a word

```
self.b0 = QLabel(self) etc...
letter_dict = {'b':3,'c':3,'d':3,'f':3,'g':3,'h':3,'k':3,'l':3,'m':3,'n':3,'p':3,'r':3,'s':3,'t':3,'v':3,'w':3,'y':3}

for letter in letter_dict:
          letterposition = letter +str(letter_dict[letter])
          print(letterposition)
```

I want to then update the label called b0, or b1 etc. accordingly.
I tried using `self.letterposition.setText(letter)` , as that should call self.b0.setText(letter). That doesn't seem to be working. I assume it's something to do with the self. instance interacting with a variable?
This isn't the whole code, but everything else seems to be working.

Comment: "a bunch of different labels called b0, b1...b6...d1..." You should learn about lists.

Comment: @Yaya77 As already suggested in your other question, creating each instance like that is highly discouraged: it's ineffective, makes the code unnecessarily long, difficult to maintain and prone to errors and problems. Really, don't do this, it's just bad (if not terrible) practice, and if you keep asking questions that are obviously related to this aspect, nobody will answer you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a list:

```
class MyApp:
    def __init__():
        self.labels = [QLabel(self) for _ in range(7)]
```

Now you can do something like

```
self.labels[0].setText(letter)
```

But you don't have to use `0` explicitly. You can use a variable instead.

For a grid, you can create a list of lists. I'll leave the details as an exercise for the reader.